# How to count data within a Pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there a quick/easy way of counting the different fields that are listed within a Pivot table.

For example, if I had data which listed different car manufacturers in an inventory and the color of the cars, how would I get a quick count of the different colors?

In the below example, I just want to get a quick count of the different colours (I.e. 3 for MB, 2 for Audi, 3 for BMW)

```
Mercedes-Benz 10
-Black 3
-Silver 2
-Grey 5

Audi 5
-White 3
-Blue 2

BMW 15
-Red 8
-Green 2
-Yellow 5
```

Comment: just remove whatever your numbers columns  are from the PivotTable Fields Values section and move the colours to the Values section

Comment: COUNT？You can change the Value fields setting to COUNT.